# Why __set_name__ does not get called for a StringField/flask_wtf

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, python-3.7

Anybody knows why the hook **set_name** (added by a decoration function) does not get called for a StringField/flask_wtf class. While it gets called for a 'simply constructed' class? as it is clear in the following code:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, BooleanField, SubmitField, SelectField, IntegerField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Email, ValidationError, StopValidation
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, redirect, url_for, request, jsonify, session

def AddSetName(Cl) :
    class ClsWithSetName(Cl):
        def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
            print("Set Name ", self, owner, name,super(Cl,self))
#            super(Cl,self).__set_name__(self,owner,name)
            self.key = name
            try:
                owner.KeyFields.append(name)
            except :
                owner.KeyFields = [name]

    return ClsWithSetName

class Trait(object):
    def __init__(self, minimum, maximum):
        self.minimum = minimum
        self.maximum = maximum

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        print("get called ", self, instance, owner)
        return instance.__dict__[self.key]

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        print("Set called ", self, instance, value)
        if self.minimum < value < self.maximum:
            instance.__dict__[self.key] = value
        else:
            raise ValueError("value not in range")

Trait = AddSetName(Trait)
StringField = AddSetName(StringField)

class T1:
    Val1=Trait(0,10)
    Val2=Trait(0,5)

class FrmLogin(FlaskForm):
    username=StringField('username', validators=[DataRequired])
    password=StringField('password', validators=[DataRequired])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass
    print(dir(StringField))
#    x = T1()
#    x.Val1 = 8
#    x.Val2 = 4
#    print(x)
#    print(T1.KeyFields)

>>> Set Name  <__main__.AddSetName.<locals>.ClsWithSetName object at 0x0000018E2A0FDD88> <class '__main__.T1'> Val1 <super: <class 'Trait'>, <ClsWithSetName object>>
>>>Set Name  <__main__.AddSetName.<locals>.ClsWithSetName object at 0x0000018E2A0FDE08> <class '__main__.T1'> Val2 <super: <class 'Trait'>, <ClsWithSetName object>>
>>>['__call__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__html__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__unicode__', '__weakref__', '_formfield', '_run_validation_chain', '_translations', '_value', 'do_not_call_in_templates', 'errors', 'gettext', 'ngettext', 'populate_obj', 'post_validate', 'pre_validate', 'process', 'process_data', 'process_errors', 'process_formdata', 'raw_data', 'validate', 'validators', 'widget']
```

The output does not show any call to set_name for StringField !

Any suggestion to 'reactivate' or imitate this call?

Answer (score 1):

There is a situation which might lead to ‘non call to **set_name**’ of a class: When the class contains a definition of **new** that does not return an instance (returns None) of an object as it is expected. Without the instance, python does not call **init** neither **set_name** of that class.

I tried to examine this case especially with a StringField component :

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired
from flask import Flask


app = Flask(__name__ )

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def MainPage():
    Frm = FrmLogin()


def AddSetName(Cl) :
    class ClsWithSetName(Cl):
        def __new__(cls, *args, **Kargs):
            if len(Kargs) == 0 :
                inst = super(ClsWithSetName, cls).__new__(cls)
            else:
                inst = super(ClsWithSetName, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **Kargs)
            print("new ", inst)
            return inst

        def __init__(self, *args, **Kargs):
            super(ClsWithSetName, self).__init__(*args, **Kargs)
            print("init get called")

        def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
            print("Set Name ", self, owner, name,super(Cl,self))
#            super(Cl,self).__set_name__(self,owner,name)
            self.key = name
            try:
                owner.KeyFields.append(name)
            except :
                owner.KeyFields = [name]

    return ClsWithSetName

class Trait(object):
    def __init__(self, minimum, maximum):
        self.minimum = minimum
        self.maximum = maximum

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        print("get called ", self, instance, owner)
        return instance.__dict__[self.key]

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        print("Set called ", self, instance, value)
        if self.minimum < value < self.maximum:
            instance.__dict__[self.key] = value
        else:
            raise ValueError("value not in range")

Trait = AddSetName(Trait)
StringField = AddSetName(StringField)

class T1:
    Val1=Trait(0,10)
#    Val2=Trait(0,5)
    pass

class FrmLogin(FlaskForm):
    username=StringField('username', validators=[DataRequired])
#    password=StringField('password', validators=[DataRequired])
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass

>>> new  <__main__.AddSetName.<locals>.ClsWithSetName object at 0x0000017F46386348>
>>> init get called
>>> Set Name  <__main__.AddSetName.<locals>.ClsWithSetName object at 0x0000017F46386348> <class '__main__.T1'> Val1 <super: <class 'Trait'>, <ClsWithSetName object>>

>>> new  <UnboundField(ClsWithSetName, ('username',), {'validators': [<class 'wtforms.validators.DataRequired'>]})>
```

If we swipe out the ‘return’ instruction in **new** hook, neither **init** or **set_name** are called.
At the same time, the print shows that the original **new** call returns an object (at a specific address) for ‘Trait’ field, while in case of StringField it does not return an object (no address associated with), but a class named ‘UnboundField’.
However, not returning an object from **new** is an unusual behavior, the missing of the object instance makes the call of either **init** or **set_name** meaningless.

This may answer my question “why **set_name** does not get called”, but it does not give an alternative to imitate it.

Comment: I am becoming more active on Stackoverflow... whatever, I need my score to be raised up.